# imap credentials not working when listening to new mail event using node mail-notifier2 module

Tags: node.js, notifications, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

```
var notifier = require('mail-notifier');   
    var imap = {
           username: "siddharthsogani1",
           password: "MYGMAILPASSWORD",
           host: "imap.gmail.com",
           port: 993, // imap port 
           secure: true // use secure connection 
    };

notifier(imap).on('mail',function(mail){console.log(mail);}).start();
```

I am trying to listen to new mail event in my gmail inbox. I am using node mail-notifier2 module to do so (as shown in code snippet above). However, I am not able to authenticate.

When I am using above code I get error:-'uncaughtException: Timed out while authenticating with server' and when I am passing tls: true in imap object then I get uncaught exception: 'uncaughtException: self signed certificate in certificate chain'. Please let me know where I am wrong and what should I do to make this work?

Comment: Since you're using NodeJS, try the [NodeJS Quickstart for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and follow the OAuth flow. With regard to the error, check this [github forum](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2061) where the suggested alternatives are a) Do SSL termination at your load balancer
b) Use a free certificate.

Comment: @noogui thanks a lot! the github forum helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in this forum: https://github.com/request/request/issues/2061

As answered The trick is to set
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
With that fake SSL auth can be used to inspect client and server communications